# How to add Google Verification code html file for particular url in codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, google-search-console

I am new with google webmaster tools.
I have website and my client has SEO person fot site.
SEO person ask me to add google verification code html file on root so i added this on root of website.
Now SEO person ask me to add verification code html file on particular link.
How can i add this ?

For example:
My website is name as  www.xyz.com first i added verification code file (google7894edf.html) on root level so i can see html file by accessing path like
www.xyz.com/google7894edf.html.
But how can i add verification file for particular link.  **www.xyz.com/search** and **www.xyz.com/find**

Beacause search and find are the controllers.

Comment: why you need to add that verification code file because you have already verified your website by adding at root path .?

Comment: SEO person ask me to do that. Is it wrong ?

Comment: For more information about verify ur website see that link
https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/176793?hl=en

Comment: Usually, you verify a domain name, and not urls. If you want to verify the url also, just echo the text inside `google7894edf.html` in the corresponding controller.